# Define x,y of line (start/end) connector for two shapes KineticJS/HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs, shapes

I'm working in a small project where I'll need create a resizable parent shape and a resizable child shape with a connection line. I did​​ in KinecticJS.
But, I have a problem for calculate the x1, x2 (start connector) and x2,y2 (end connector) when the shape is resizing.

This calculate is in the function addConnection:

```
var x1 = parentNode.getX() + rectParent.getWidth()/2;
var y1 = parentNode.getY() + rectParent.getHeight()/2;
var x2 = childNode.getX() + rectChild.getWidth()/2; 
var y2 = childNode.getY() + rectChild.getHeight()/2;
```

I put my working code in http://jsfiddle.net/geremora/nxDNH/

My Javascript code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});

var groupRoot = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 100,
    y: 50,
    draggable: true,
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

layer.add(groupRoot);
stage.add(layer);

newRect(groupRoot);
var groupChild = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 270,
    y: 100,
    draggable: true
});

layer.add(groupChild);
newRect(groupChild);
var con = addConnection(groupRoot, groupChild);
layer.add(con);
con.moveToBottom();
stage.draw();


function newRect(group){
        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          fill: 'blue',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          name:'rect'
          });

          group.add(rect);
          addAnchor(group, rect.x, rect.y, 'topLeft');
          addAnchor(group, rect.getWidth(), rect.y, 'topRight');
          addAnchor(group, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight(), 'bottomRight');
          addAnchor(group, rect.x, rect.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft');

          group.on('dragstart', function() {
          this.moveToTop();
          });

        stage.draw();
 }

function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var rect = group.get('.rect')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();


        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
          case 'topLeft':
            topRight.setY(anchorY);
            bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'topRight':
            topLeft.setY(anchorY);
            bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
            break;
          case 'bottomRight':
            bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
            topRight.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
          case 'bottomLeft':
            bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
            topLeft.setX(anchorX); 
            break;
        }

        rect.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if(width && height) {
          rect.setSize(width, height);
        }
}

function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var stage = group.getStage();
        var layer = group.getLayer();

        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          stroke: '#666',
          fill: '#ddd',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          radius: 5,
          name: name,
          draggable: true,
          dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
          update(this);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
          group.setDraggable(false);
          this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function() {
          group.setDraggable(true);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          this.setStrokeWidth(4);
          layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
          var layer = this.getLayer();
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
          this.setStrokeWidth(2);
          layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
}
function addConnection(parentNode, childNode){

 var connector = new Kinetic.Line({
              drawFunc: function (canvas) {

                  var rectParent = parentNode.get('.rect')[0];
                  var rectChild = childNode.get('.rect')[0];
                  var ctx = canvas.getContext();
                  var x1 = parentNode.getX() + rectParent.getWidth()/2;
                  var y1 = parentNode.getY() + rectParent.getHeight()/2;
                  var x2 = childNode.getX() + rectChild.getWidth()/2; 
                  var y2 = childNode.getY() + rectChild.getHeight()/2;
                  ctx.save();
                  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
                  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
                  ctx.stroke();
                  ctx.restore();
              },
              points: [1, 1, 1, 3],
              stroke: "red",
              strokeWidth: 2,
              lineCap: 'round',
              lineJoin: 'round',
              opacity: 1,
              draggable: false
      });
  return connector;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem: when you are moving, for example, topLeft anchor, you are changing X position of rectange. But X position of group is not changing. So solution - add rect position when are are calculating position of connector:

```
var x1 = parentNode.getX() + rectParent.getX()+ rectParent.getWidth()/2;
var y1 = parentNode.getY() + rectParent.getY() + rectParent.getHeight()/2;
var x2 = childNode.getX() + rectChild.getX()+ rectChild.getWidth()/2; 
var y2 = childNode.getY() + rectChild.getY() + rectChild.getHeight()/2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/pAQKx/